# I have multiple versions of the same landing page. How can I tell Google Analytics which is being viewed?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I'm sending a link to a landing page to a number of different companies and need to be able to tell Google Analytics which company is viewing the page and when. I of course have my original link to the page tagged with UTM parameters accordingly, but I also need to build in a safety net in case someone passes the link around and removes that code.

The URL for the landing page looks like this:

`http://www.website.com/landing_page/company_name/`

The `company_name` part is not an actual directory on the server but part of a query string that I'm rewriting into the URI, so I don't believe I will be able to filter on that in Google Analytics. The `company_name` part will change depending on who I send it to.

So, I need to be able to add some sort of tag or flag in my GA code to tell GA which company is viewing the page.

How might I do that? What are my options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify page URL in Google Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398110/how-to-modify-page-url-in-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'Company',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
      $_GET['company_name'],               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

That **must** be called before you call _trackPageview(). You can read more about custom variables here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables